# Undefined offset: 0 in edit function

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I had this working then when I added the new category `Quantity` it now produces this error.

```
Undefined offset: 0 in (the form values)
```

I cannot see where the undefined offset is. Any help would be appreciated.

I also know mysql is depreciated but want it working before changing.

As a note, all the data is recalled to the edit form it is when you process it, it produces that error

Also the query has been validated and runs.

**Edit Function**

```
function edit_product($id, $name, $description, $price, $quantity, $picture, $category) {

      $id           = (int) $id;  
      $category     = (int) $category;
      $name         = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
      $description  = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
      $price        = mysql_real_escape_string($price);
      $quantity     = (int) $quantity;
      $picture      = mysql_real_escape_string($picture);



      mysql_query("UPDATE `shop` SET 

      `prod_id`         = {$category},
      `name`            = '{$name}',
      `description`     = '{$description}',
      `price`           = '{$price}',
      `quantity`        = '{$quantity}',
      `picture`         = '{$picture}'
      WHERE `id`        = {$id}");

    echo mysql_error();
    }
```

**Edit page**

```
    $post = get_posts($_GET['id']);

    if ( isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['picture'], $_POST['category']) ) {
    $errors = array();

        $name           = trim($_POST['name']);
        $description    = trim($_POST['description']);
        $price          = trim($_POST['price']);
        $quantity       = trim($_POST['quantity']);
        $picture        = trim($_POST['picture']);


        if ( empty($name) ) {
            $errors[] = 'You need to supply a title';
        }   else if ( strlen($name) > 255 ) {
        $errors[] = 'Title cannot be longer than 255 characters';
        }

        if ( empty($description) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
        }

        if ( empty($price) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
        }

        if ( empty($quantity) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
        }

        if ( empty($picture) ) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to supply text';
        }

        if (! category_exists('id', $_POST['category']) ) {
        $errors[] = 'Category does not exist';

        }

        if ( empty($errors) ) {
        edit_product($_GET['id'], $name, $description, $price, $quantity, $picture, $_POST['category']);
        header("Location: ../admin/edit_products.php?id={$post[0]['post_id']}");
        die();
        }
    }
    ?>

.....

<label for="name">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $post[0]['name']; ?>"><br/>
<label for="price">price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $post[0]['price']; ?>"><br/>

<label for="sale">Quantity</label>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $post[0]['quantity']; ?>"><br/>
<label for="picture">Picture</label>
<input type="text" name="picture" value="<?php echo $post[0]['picture']; ?>"><br/>


<label for="description">Description</label>
<textarea  name="description" rows="15" cols="50"><?php echo $post[0]['description']; ?></textarea><br/>


<label for="prod_id">Category</label>
<select name="category">
<?php
foreach ( get_categories() as $category ) {
$selected = ( $category['name'] == $post[0]['name'] ) ? " selected" : '';
?>

<option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>


--------------
```

**Get Post function**  - As requested.

```
function get_posts($id = null, $cat_id = null) {
    $posts = array();

    $query ="SELECT  `shop`.`id` AS  `post_id` ,  `products_cat`.`id` AS  `category_id` , `shop`.`name` ,  `description` ,  `price` ,  `quantity` ,  `picture` 
FROM  `shop` 
INNER JOIN  `products_cat` ON  `shop`.`prod_id` =  `products_cat`.`id` ";

    if ( isset($id) ) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query .= " WHERE `shop`.`id` = {$id}";
    }

    if ( isset($cat_id) ) {
        $cat_id = (int) $cat_id;
        $query .= " WHERE `products_cat`.`id` = {$cat_id}";
}

    $query .= " ORDER BY `shop`.`price` DESC";

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    echo mysql_error();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
        $posts[] = $row;
        }

    return $posts;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's in your edit function and not somewhere you're referencing `$post[0]...`?

Comment: I'm just looking at your code and seeing you have `prod_id = {$category},` - Should't it be `prod_id = '{$category}',` - With the `'`? ... Just checking...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: is $post an array? What exactly does this get_posts() function do?

Comment: Is `$post = get_posts($_GET['id']);` returning an array or is it empty? Might want to run a `print_r($post)` to make sure it is getting something. Otherwise `$post[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: I have added the get_post function above. it is an array. Thanks

Comment: Might be an array, but if your sql query doesn't return any results, it'll be an EMPTY array.

Comment: as a not, all the data is recalled to the edit form it is when you process it, it produces that error

Comment: also the query has been validated and runs

Comment: @user1941674 will you please provide the line no. which always dispays with eorror?

Comment: @sandip it displays errors on all the form value lines....`<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $post[0]['price']; ?>">` etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing please dont use mysql_ *and go for mysqli_*

For a while , In above code

```
Undefined offset: 0 error is cooming from lines as you said 

<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $post[0]['price']; ?>">
```

This is because the value at that index $post[**0**]['price'] has not been set yet.

Just replace it with

```
 <?php echo isset($post[0]['price'])?$post[0]['price']:''; ?>
```

in the value attribute.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Brillant. Thanks for the help sandip. You were very patient. And yeah im moving over to the other code once I get everthing sorted :)